# "-h" parameter in shell script "while" condition

Tags: shell-script, macos

I am trying to understand an already written Shell script and I have encountered following line.

```
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ];
```

What I need to know is the meaning of **-h**

As for additional information:

> $SOURCE = ./my-script.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-h` is not an option to the `while` keyword, but to the `[` (and `test`) utility.  The meaning of the option is described in the manual for either `test`, `[` or of your shell (since these are commonly built-in utilities), see `man test`.

It's a *standard* option for `test` and `[`, and the POSIX standard [describes it](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) like so:

> `-h  pathname`
>
> True if `pathname` resolves to an existing directory entry for a symbolic link. False if `pathname` cannot be resolved, or if `pathname` resolves to an existing directory entry for a file that is not a symbolic link. If the final component of `pathname` is a symbolic link, that symbolic link is not followed.

In short, it evaluates to *true* if the given pathname is a symbolic link, so your `while` loop would loop until the value in the variable `SOURCE` no longer refers to a symbolic link.